# xUnit.Net - is it possible to ignore an entire namespace?

Tags: .net, testing, xunit.net

In my test assembly I frequently have a Spikes directory where I put...well...spike code from early in the project.

I rarely maintain or even run these tests as they usually have to do with connecting to other systems and concern use cases covered by other tests.

Is it possible to mark the entire namespace as ignored in xUnit or should I just delete the code?

Comment: Any reason not to put it in an entirely separate project? That's what I'd do...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I've done that in the past, but I'm trying to keep the number of projects down, especially projects that I need to create early on. Thinking about this for an hour, maybe the 'correct' thing to do is to delete these tests and let them fade into the annals of source control.